# How to navigate to a different screen with onTap in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to navigate the user to a different screen when the user taps on a button in the alert dialogue, so i wrapped the container with inkwell and then used onTap () and navigator push replacement :

```
onTap: (){
           Navigator.pushReplacement(
           context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Subscription ()),);
          }
```

but this gives me an error saying : error:  `3 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.`

Full Block of InkWell()

```
child: InkWell(
                            child: Container(
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                "Subscribe Now",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    color: textColor,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ))),
                              onTap: (){
                                Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                  context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Subscription ()),);
                        }
                          )
```

Subscription Class:

```
    class Subscription extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool isPaymentSuccess;
  final User currentUser;
  final Map items;
  Subscription(this.currentUser, this.isPaymentSuccess, this.items);

  @override
  _SubscriptionState createState() => _SubscriptionState();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass yoru parameters with the naviagtion, like this:

```
onTap:(){
Navigator.pushReplacement(
  context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Subscription (true, currentUser,items) //here pass the actual values of these variables, for example false if the payment isn't successfull..etc
),);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The subscription page is having 3 parameter you need to pass in...

You need pass in values for

```
Final bool ispaymentSuccess;
Final User currentUser;
Final Map items;
```

That is why the error is coming up...

For better user experience...
Give all subscription constructor @required so that it will require you to pass in those value when you want to navigate to the page...

Like this

```
Subscription({@required this.isPaymentSuccess, @required this.items, @required this.currentUser});
```